# how to put procedure inside package

Tags: plsql

I have a package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pack1
AS
PROCEDURE details;
END pack1;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack1
AS
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE details
    IS
    BEGIN
    select *
    FROM table1;
    END details;
END;
/
```

But I am getting error message

```
Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.
```

I am new to pl/sql, and trying to learn how to use package and procedure. I know my code might be far from correct. Tell me what changes i can do in my code to make it work

Comment: Just go through  any tutorial online, for eg: this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_packages.htm

Comment: Instead of just showing the code that worked, why not show what *didn't* work?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp see the above code..this is the code which is not working

Comment: You need to store the result of the select somewhere. You can't just run a select like that and discard the result

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you tell me how to store the result of select?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/overview.html#GUID-2FBCFBBE-6B42-4DB8-83F3-55B63B75B1EB

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know about this document, but I was still not able to solve my problem. That is why I am asking here for help.

Comment: You don't `create or replace` a procedure within a package - just declare it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
PROCEDURE details
```

instead of

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE details
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#LNPLS00905

On the other hand, the **SELECT** statement needs a **INTO** statement. So the code could be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pack1
AS
  PROCEDURE details;
END pack1;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack1
AS
  PROCEDURE details
  IS
    l_rec  table1%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT *
      INTO l_rec
      FROM table1;
  END details;
END pack1;
```